# Uncaught ReferenceError: helloSpeaker is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to code something, but I couldn't make it work. I've defined jQuery too, but it didn't solve the problem. It says:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: helloSpeaker is not defined

```js
(function(window) {
  var helloSpeaker = {};
  helloSpeaker.speak = function(name) {
    console.log(speakWord + " " + helloSpeaker.name);
  }
  var speakWord = "Hello";
  window.helloSpeaker = helloSpeaker;
}(window));

//script.js
(function() {
  var names = ["Yaakov", "John", "Jen", "Jason", "Paul", "Frank", "Larry", "Paula", "Laura", "Jim"];
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var firstLetter = names[i].charAt(0).toLowerCase();
    if (firstLetter === 'j') {
      byeSpeaker.speak(names[i]);
    } else {
      helloSpeaker.speak(names[i]);
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Module 4 Solution Starter</title>
  <script src="SpeakHello.js"></script>
  <script src="SpeakGoodBye.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: please try to mention the error you get

Comment: please paste your all codes and explain what do you want to achieve

Comment: You've shown the code which defines `helloSpeaker()`, but not the code which uses it and causes the error.

Comment: @Berg_Durden it shouldn't matter, since the variable declaration gets hoisted to the top of the function definition (the initialization happens where it is written).

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet where it works fine, up to the point you invoke `byeSpeaker`, but that's simply because it's not defined in the example. The code you've shown does not demonstrate the issue you describe

Comment: Oh, there's a byeSpeaker, but it is the same as helloSpeaker.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to access the `name` **argument** that is passed in, which you do with just `name`, not `helloSpeaker.name`.

```js
(function(window) {
  var helloSpeaker = {};
  helloSpeaker.speak = function(name) {
    console.log(speakWord + " " + name);
  }
  var speakWord = "Hello";
  window.helloSpeaker = helloSpeaker;
}(window));

//script.js
(function() {
  var names = ["Yaakov", "John", "Jen", "Jason", "Paul", "Frank", "Larry", "Paula", "Laura", "Jim"];
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var firstLetter = names[i].charAt(0).toLowerCase();
    if (firstLetter === 'j') {
      //byeSpeaker.speak(names[i]);
    } else {
      helloSpeaker.speak(names[i]);
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Module 4 Solution Starter</title>
  <script src="SpeakHello.js"></script>
  <script src="SpeakGoodBye.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Also, it is bad practice to attach new properties and methods to the `window` (Global) object, so unless you have some particular reason for doing so, you should avoid that.